# Not able to trigger click/tap event in mobile in jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to trigger `click/tap` on an element. However I am not able to get it to work on both mobile and website. To test on mobile I am selecting a mobile device in the device tool bar through 'inspect' in chrome.

I have tried following methods:

1: Works in Website, not in mobile:      `document.getElementById('hint1').click();`

2: Does not work at in both: `$('#hint1').click();`

3: Works in website, not in mobile: `$('#hint1')[0].click();`

4: Doesnt work in both:

```
 var e = new Event('touchstart');
 $('#hint1')[0].dispatchEvent(e);
```

`#hint1` is a link, with a few extra classes. I cant imagine that classes are affecting the mobile interaction:

```
<a id="hint1" href="#" class="open-popover link" data-popover=".settings-popover" style="font-size: 30px;"><i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

Comment: Why not just call the function that's triggered when that element is clicked?

Comment: Somehow the cSS of the modal that opens if I do it directly is not working

Answer (score 0):

Using this for mobile devices,

```
$(document).on('click touchstart', function () {});
```

or

```
$(document).on('click touch', function () {});
```

The touchstart event fires as soon as an element is touched, the touch event is more like a "tap"

Comment: Hi, I want to trigger an event thru program (and not user interaction). Your solution is about doing something once the event is triggered